# If the bot doesn't find a role, it creates one

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried the method

```
let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');
let warnRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');
```

but I didn't find any way to create a role with the similar name. Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only to  `FIND` roles . If you want to create a role is like this :

```
let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member') return false;
    let warnRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted') return false;
    message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
            name: "member",
            color: "#ff0000",
            permissions: 0
        }
    }).then(role => {
        message.channel.send(`Role \`${role.name}\` created!`);
    });
```